# Woocommerce Product Attribute Values picked from Upsell and Cross Sell

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am displaying Upsell and Cross sell products on single product page. But unfortunately The Additional information tab which contains the attribute are picking from Upsell and Cross sell.

When i remove the Upsell and crosssell loop, the attributes values become correct. but as soon as i add the loop to display upsell and cross sell it pick the attribute value from upsell/cross sell.

My page is: http://www.healthgenie.in/incofit-premium-adult-diapers-medium-pack-10-71cm-101cm-28-40/

Comment: are you using custom code for upsell and cross sell? if so make sure to reset the loop https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by resetting the loop query.

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```